# A7S Remote Control

Tags: camera, sony

I would like to use the A7s via USB Remote Trigger with the following parameters for a user interface on screen:

Windows 7 Pro, no other OS at this time
There will be no lenses attached, so must work with no lens
Manual mode only
Control contrast, sharpening, etc. plus picture style (color and monochrome only)
Control ISO and shutter speed
Invert image for display (not just vertical or horizontal flip)
image should display immediately after capture (less than .75 seconds)
Image will be jpeg, equivalent of medium/fine resolution

Transfer the inbound image from the A7S to another directory in Windows 7
Any image capture and storage cannot be embedded in directories, prefer just straight throughput without saving.

This is not a wireless application.  Can the Remote API or even Remote Capture Control (if can be modified) be used to accomplish this project?

Thank you for you kind consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Sony A7s camera supports Camera Remote API. This will allow you to control the camera remotely and fetch recorded media over WLAN.

The API works over HTTP. So you can actually use it on a Windows computer. You can find a guide documentation in Camera Remote SDK zip file. In this guide, you will find detailed information on each feature provided by API such as; ISO, Zoom, Quality settings etc.

For supported API features on Sony A7s camera, please check out table on following page:
https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/